# Using Android navigation controller and finishing the calling activity

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

I have an activity that is using the navigation component to flow through my fragments to get info from the user in a wizard style. I have a dead end fragment in my flow where I tell the user why they can't continue and I want to provide a done/cancel button that finishes the activity that the nav controller is in and leaves the user at the screen they left off on.

I tried adding the activity they launch the flow from as an action destination but that launches the activity as a new activity and isn't where the user left from.

I can grab the activity from the fragment and call finish() on that activity from the button click but that didn't seem like the way one is supposed to use the nav graph. Am I wrong? Is there a way to say in a nav graph direction to just exit the everything?

Answer (score 4):

There's no `navigate()` operation that will pop activities off the stack - the only back stack that the `NavController` is aware of is the internal back stack it manages.

If you want to finish an activity, call `finish()` on your activity.